# Change the font size and color of first row of table

Tags: html, css, angular7

I want display cricket team details. First row of a table is the captains, so for every first row color, I want to make the font size to be green and bold

This is My HTML:

```
 <div >
     <table id="sports" border=1 align=center >
         <thead >
         <tr>
             <th>Team1</th>
             <th>Team2</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody  *ngFor="let T of Teams" >
                 <td> {{T.Indian_players}}</td>
                 <td>{{T.Australia_players}}</td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

This is my model, where I have taken static data:

```
export const Players=[
        {Indian_players:'Kohili(c)',Australia_players:'David Warner(c)',Pakistan_players:'shaheen Afridi(c)',Southafrica_players:'dale steyn(c)',England_players:'Harry Kane(c)'},
        {Indian_players:' Dhoni',Australia_players:'Steve Smith',Pakistan_players:'sarfraz Ahmed',Southafrica_players:'du plessis',England_players:'Joe Root'},
        {Indian_players:'Rohit Sharma',Australia_players:'Glen Maxwell',Pakistan_players:'Babar Azam',Southafrica_players:'Imran Tahir',England_players:'Alex Hales'},
        {Indian_players:'Jadeja',Australia_players:'Aron Finch',Pakistan_players:'Mohamad Hafeez',Southafrica_players:'David Miller',England_players:'James Anderson'},
        {Indian_players:'K.L.Rahul',Australia_players:'Mitchel Starc',Pakistan_players:'Imad Wasim',Southafrica_players:'Jp duminy',England_players:'Moeen Ali'},
        {Indian_players:'Bhuvaneswar Kumar',Australia_players:'Travis Head',Pakistan_players:'Shadab khan',Southafrica_players:'de kock',England_players:'Jos Buttler'},
        {Indian_players:'Shikar Dhawan',Australia_players:'Pat cummins',Pakistan_players:'yasir shah',Southafrica_players:'Hashim Amla',England_players:'Ben Strokes'},
        {Indian_players:'RishabPanth',Australia_players:'Mitchel Marsh',Pakistan_players:'Imam-ul-haq',Southafrica_players:'chris morris',England_players:'Sam Billings'},
        {Indian_players:'Ashwin',Australia_players:'Peter siddle',Pakistan_players:'Faheem Ashraf',Southafrica_players:'Aiden markram',England_players:'Eoin Morgan'},
        {Indian_players:'Dinesh Karthik',Australia_players:'Tim Paine',Pakistan_players:'Shoib Malik',Southafrica_players:'Dean Elgar',England_players:'chris Woakes'},
```

Comment: _first row of table_ do you mean table header?

Comment: Note that the HTML structure you provided is invalid, you are missing an opening `<tr>` tag inside your table body. I'm also suspicious that you're using `*ngFor` on your `tbody` instead of a `tr`.

Comment: No am not getting that

Comment: I have added that <tr> tag too

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let T of Teams; let i = index" [class.your-captain-css-class]="index===0">
        <td> {{T.Indian_players}}</td>
        <td>{{T.Australia_players}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've done the following.

1. getting the index along with object.
2. Adding class if index is `0`.

This is cover your requirement. There is another way of doing it only by CSS.

Comment: can u please do it just by CSS

Comment: @geethaareti I think adding a class by this method is more efficient than by CSS. Using `nth-of` operator in CSS is not encouraged.

Comment: ok but i didnt get what i want i have added the same class to my <tr> but i couldnt get

Comment: how to add style to that index

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS by doing this

```
custom-class:first-child { 
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 15px;
}
```

Also, you have an error in your sample an ending tr tag but no beginning tr tag inside the body

```
<tbody  *ngFor="let T of Teams" >
       <td> {{T.Indian_players}}</td>
       <td>{{T.Australia_players}}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

I believe after reading the comments you could/should do this instead and use the CSS at the top and it should all work the reason I suggest using the class instead of tr is because if you are using tr you have used tr more then once and it will affect all tr tags instead of just the one you want in the body.

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let T of Teams" class="custom-class">
        <td> {{T.Indian_players}}</td>
        <td>{{T.Australia_players}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No it wont work for me still player name is not changing.Actually i didn't write any logic for captain i just gave as (c) after the name.So is there any way to get with index

Comment: yea if you do *ngfor="let T of Teams; let i = index" and then you can use i anywhere within the block as the current index